# SQL While loop out of sorts

Tags: sql, if-statement, while-loop, create-table

Trying to use a while loop to input date data types into a table. My loop break doesn't work and the input values are coming out as NULL.

Help would be greatly appreciated

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @countIndex INT
DECLARE @yearDate DATE
DECLARE @todaysDate DATE
SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
SET @yearDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1,@StartDate)

CREATE TABLE DateLookup
    (
    DateID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    DateDescription Date
    )

 WHILE (DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate, @yearDate)) <= 366   
 BEGIN

    SET @countIndex = @countIndex +1

    INSERT INTO DateLookup (DateDescription)
    VALUES (DATEADD (DD,@countIndex,@todaysDate))--DAY(GETDATE()))

    IF (@countIndex < 366)
        Break

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `DECLARE @todaysDate DATE = getdate()` and `DECLARE @countIndex INT = 0`

Also, you probably meant `IF (@countIndex > 365) BREAK`

Comment: +1  . . . I missed this answer, which I think is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

YOu never set @countIndex to 0; it's a NULL, which means it will always be NULL when you add 1 to it.  Same problem with @todaysDate.

If you want to avoid the WHILE Loop altogether, you can kludge something together like so:

```
; WITH    seed
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY name ) AS n
               FROM     sys.columns
             )
    SELECT TOP 366
            DATEADD(Day, n - 1, GETDATE())
    FROM    seed
```

Comment: That won't necessarily give you 365 days -- see my answer -- this depends on how many rows are in your sys.columns table.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is insert the next 365 days in your DateLookup table, why not use something like this (assuming you're meaning SQL Server, depends on your RDBMS):

```
INSERT INTO DateLookup  (DateDescription)
SELECT DATEADD(DD,Number,GETDATE())
FROM master..spt_values 
WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 365 AND Type = 'P'
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cd2f/1).

Good luck.